# Blueprint fixes menu height

Tags: asp.net, css, blueprint-css

When the following markup renders, the menu renders as table `topMainMenu` with a height of 51.  When I remove the Blueprint stylesheet, `topMainMenu` renders with a height of 20, the minimum I presume.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Blueprint/screen.css" />
    <script src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" runat="server">
    <div class="prepend-1 span-22 last">
        <asp:Menu ID="topMainMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="mainMenuDataSource" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="100%" Height="16px">
            <StaticMenuStyle Height="10px" BackColor="Navy" />
        </asp:Menu>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I was under the impression that Blueprint should have no effect on any height in this scenario.  Surely a CSS reset wont be doing *this*?  No styling I have tried can shrink the menu height below 51.  What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should override your blueprint css

```
<div class="prepend-1 span-22 last" style="height:20px;line-height:20px;">
```

OR

```
<style>
.adjustHeight {
    height:20px; line-height:20px; margin:0; padding:0;
}
</style>
<div class="prepend-1 span-22 last adjustHeight">
```

Comment: use firebug to debug css properties, it gives you exact idea which element is exceeding the height.

Comment: I've tried, I cant see anything exact.  I'm redoing the menu using a UL to see it that helps.